# Does dynamically-allocated memory need to be freed inside a loop of undetermined number of cycles?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

#### Undefined behaviour when trying to keep a string buffer inside a loop in C.

Hello all! I seem to be getting undefined behaviour when introducing any `calloc` or `malloc` allocation methods, although I have tried to follow everything I've found about freeing and deallocating. This is snippet of code is running inside an infinite loop so I suppose that might have something to do with it?

###### Context: Trying to update the coefficients for digital filter on an FPGA board simulating a NIOS II processor.

For the moment I have dummed down the code a little to simply start collecting characters into a `buffer` after the `c` character is sent, and stop collecting after the `x` character is sent. It can be assumed in this case that no more than 30 characters are being sent between the `c` and `x`, that is handled on the host side by a tested python script.

```c
} else if (prompt == 'c') {  // check that control signal = c

    // let host know that 'c' is received
    printf("BOARD: preparing for coefficient update\n");
    
    // MEMORY ALLOCATION
    char *buffer = calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    buffer[30] = '\0'; // set a null pointer at the end of string
    
    // check, this should print a blank character
    printf("buffer init is : %c\n", buffer[0]); 

    int count = 0;

    prompt = getc(fp); // reads from jtag_uart interface (tested and working)

    while (prompt != 'x'){
        buffer[count] = prompt;
        printf("buffer inside loop is : %s\n", buffer);
        printf("BOARD >>  Received: %c\n", prompt);
        prompt = getc(fp);
        count++;
    }

    free(buffer);
    buffer=NULL;

}
```

The 'undefined' behaviour is only to do with the `buffer`: Sometimes it prints in the terminal (this is what I want it to do):

```c
MESSAGE STREAM:
 ['1', '.', '2', ',', '3', '.', '5', ',']
BOARD: preparing for coefficient update
buffer init is :  // <----------------------------
initiating transmission....
HOST: sending 1

buffer inside loop is : 1

BOARD >>  Received: 1

HOST: sending .

buffer inside loop is : 1.

BOARD >>  Received: .

HOST: sending 2

buffer inside loop is : 1.2

BOARD >>  Received: 2

HOST: sending ,
buffer inside loop is : 1.2,

BOARD >>  Received: ,

HOST: sending 3

buffer inside loop is : 1.2,3

BOARD >>  Received: 3

HOST: sending .

buffer inside loop is : 1.2,3.

BOARD >>  Received: .

HOST: sending 5

buffer inside loop is : 1.2,3.5

BOARD >>  Received: 5

HOST: sending ,
buffer inside loop is : 1.2,3.5,

BOARD >>  Received: ,

end of transmission
```

And sometimes it doesn't:

```
MESSAGE STREAM:
 ['3', '.', '4', '5', ',', '2', '.', '4', '4', ',']
BOARD: preparing for coefficient update

initiating transmission....
HOST: sending 3
BOARD >>  Received: 3
HOST: sending .
BOARD >>  Received: .
HOST: sending 4
BOARD >>  Received: 4
HOST: sending 5
BOARD >>  Received: 5
HOST: sending ,
BOARD >>  Received: ,
HOST: sending 2
BOARD >>  Received: 2
HOST: sending .
BOARD >>  Received: .
HOST: sending 4
BOARD >>  Received: 4
HOST: sending 4
BOARD >>  Received: 4
HOST: sending ,
BOARD >>  Received: ,
end of transmission
```

I am assuming that this is a `c` problem as I am quite new to the concept of memory allocation, and every other function of the project is working fine - and is predictable when it isn't.

Is anyone able to spot any obvious issues here? Or let me know if I should post something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

TLDR: Tried keep a buffer of characters that is appended to in each loop cycle.

Result was undefined behaviour, sometimes it worked but more often the print statements were just skipped by the program.

Comment: `buffer[30]` is one past the end of the allocated array.

Comment: Apart from `buffer[30] = '\0'` being wrong (see previous comment), it's also useless, because `callloc` already fills the allocated buffer with 0. And the associated comment _set a null pointer at the end of string_ is meaningless. You don't set a _pointer_ here. Just remove that whole line and you should be fine (unless there are more problems elsewhere in your code)

Comment: You should read a tutorial that describes C arrays.  If an array has `n` elements, then the valid indices are `0` through `n-1`, inclusive.  In your case, you're allocating `30` elements, so the valid indices are `0` through `29`.  So what do you think writing to index `30` will do?  It's undefined behavior, and results in you posting here for help.

Comment: If you need to store 30 characters (not counting the terminating null character), then you need to allocate space for 31 characters, with the extra character being used for the null character.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake from my end, but I've tried both with and without and it's been making no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was not with memory allocation, but with printing.
For some reason, `printf` was occasionally holding back the buffer print statements. Replacing it with `fprintf` and printing to the `/dev/jtag_uart` file fixed it. Not sure why this would make a difference for only some print statements, especially since the `jtag_uart` was configured to be `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

**Off by one error:**

```
char *buffer = calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    buffer[30] = '\0';
```

*"Apart from buffer[30] = '\0' being wrong, it's also useless, because `calloc` already fills the allocated buffer with 0. And the associated comment set a null pointer at the end of string is meaningless.*" — Jabberwocky

---

*"If an array has n elements, then the valid indices are 0 through n-1, inclusive. In your case, you're allocating 30 elements, so the valid indices are 0 through 29. So what do you think writing to index 30 will do? It's undefined behavior."* — Tom Karzes

---

*"Re: but I've tried both with and without and it's been making no difference."**

Because it's undefined behaviour. It might, or might not work. Relying on it is not a good idea.

---

**Don't discard the return value of `calloc()`:**

```
char *buffer = calloc (30);
if (!buffer) {
   /* ENOMEM, handle error here */
}
```